# SSRS to excel export alignment issue of grouping plus icon

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

I have a multi-level groupings in my SSRS report. When I export the report to excel the expand icon (+) in excel is not aligned correctly. How do I fix this?

[image]